# Telegraf : How collect Hexadecimal data and apply function before insert in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I need help reading data in hexadecimal and applying a formula to transform the data.My file parse with tail :

```
2022-09-15 00:04:39 AAA99 BBB99 24 43 B2 50
2022-09-15 00:04:40 BBB99 BBB99 2C 42 F1 4B
```

And my configuration :

```
[global_tags]
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  debug = true
  quiet = false
  logtarget = "file"
  logfile = "/var/log/telegraf.log"
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = true
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://127.0.0.1:8086"]
  database = "data_hexa"
  skip_database_creation = false
  timeout = "5s"
  username = "telegraf"
  password = "***********"
  user_agent = "telegraf"
 [[outputs.file]]
   files = ["stdout", "/tmp/metrics.out"]
 [[inputs.tail]]
    files = ["/mnt/cle/hexa*.log"]
    name_override = "hexa_log"
    from_beginning = true
    max_undelivered_lines = 10000
    character_encoding = "utf-8"
    grok_patterns = ["%{CUSTOM_LOG}"]
    grok_custom_patterns = '''
CUSTOM_LOG %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp:ts-"2006-01-02 15:04:05"} %{WORD:AAAinfo:tag} %{WORD:BBBinfo:tag} %{BASE16NUM:01hexa} %{BASE16NUM:02hexa} %{BASE16NUM:03hexa} %{BASE16NUM:04hexa}
'''
    data_format = "grok"
    grok_timezone = "Local"
```

With this configuration, the data type is "string" and I want to convert the hexadecimal value to integer (IN_01hexa) and apply a change like 01hexa_convert = ((IN_01hexa)*0.8125-4.25).Then, in my database, the type of 01hexa_convert must be float.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this to convert a string of HEX to an integer via [Telegraf's converter plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/release-1.24/plugins/processors/converter).

Sample code could be as follows:

```
[[processors.converter]]
    [processors.converter.fields]
         integer = ["*hexa"]
```

As for the match processing part, it seems that we have to do it in query phase as Telegraf [doesn't have such plugin yet](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/3709).